# VScode does not compile typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am beginner at Typescript and VSCode. I have this code:

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
}

const a = async () => {
    await sleep(1000)
    console.log("BLA")
}
a()
```

but when I run it with F5, I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

pointing at `ms:` on line 1.

If I run tsc to generate js file, it works fine. How can I get VSCode to run tsc first? I have a default launch.json, tasks.json and my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
        {
            "module": "es6",
            "lib": ["es6", "DOM"],
        }
}
```

But apparently it runs `node.exe` directly on the file, which - in CLI - gives same error. But when I use `tsc` first and run `node` on .js file, it works fine.

Comment: it seems you have named your file with `.js` extension? because if it were `ts` you would get different error if you run it with node.exe

Comment: No it is .ts actually

Comment: if I run a .ts file with node I get Unknown file extension error. so which command are you running with f5?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.ts

Comment: and which node version?

Comment: $ node --version
v16.13.0

Comment: typescript files will never run in node env. You need `ts-node` to run typescript files. `ts-node` is wrapper around node env to run ts files.